# JSON Value Not Found - Unknown Field

Tags: json, graphql, gatsby, contentful

I am working with Contentful as my headless CMS for a Gatsby project. I am passing a field to each of the items in one of my content types that is initial value. some examples look like this:

```
{
    "type": "boolean",
    "initValue": true
}
```

```
{
    "type": "color",
    "initValue": null
}
```

For some reason the initValue field is the only one that I can't query from the front end. I have just added it so I am not sure if that has any issue but I have restarted my application and nothing. I even check it in the graphiql and it doesn't appear there but every other field does. I am not sure how to debug this.

** The data above is a JSON field within Contentful. **

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that graphql does type-checking within the schema which makes it so that you can't have different values for the same field. They have deep checking so that even if you set the value to an object or array with different types further down it will still check the similarity.

It is a pain to deal with for my use case but overall it is probably a good feature.